# Error with my decToBase method in C with a return

Tags: c, char, decimal, bit, radix

I am working on a method in C where I am trying to convert a decimal to its base. I am having trouble with returning a Char*. I still am unsure how to return a pointer. When I compile this code, I get a warning saying

"warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]".
and it has to do with my res character. I am uncertain with why I cannot return res, if it's a char. I don't understand what I am suppose to return if I can't return res. Please help.

```
 //return res;


char reVal(int num)
{
 if (num >= 0 && num <= 9)
 return (char)(num + '0');
 else if(num = 10)
 {
 return (char)(num - 10 + 'A');
 }
 else if(num = 11)
 {
 return (char)(num - 11 + 'B');
 }
 else if(num = 12)
 {
 return (char)(num - 12 + 'C');
 }
 else if(num = 13)
 {
 return (char)(num - 13 + 'D');
 }
 else if(num = 14)
 {
 return (char)(num - 14 + 'E');
 }
 else if(num = 15)
 {
 return (char)(num - 15 + 'F');
 }
}


// Utility function to reverse a string 
void strev(char *str)
{
  int len = strlen(str);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len/2; i++)
  {
     char temp = str[i];
     str[i] = str[len-i-1];
     str[len-i-1] = temp;
  }
}

char* decToBase(int base, int dec)
{
int index = 0; // Initialize index of result 
char res[100]; // Convert input number is given base by repeatedly 
               // dividing it by base and taking remainder 
while (dec > 0)
{
    res[index++] = reVal(dec % base);
    dec /= base;
}

res[index] = '\0';
// Reverse the result 
strev(res);
return res;

int main()
{
    char* base = decToBase(16, 248);
}
```

Regardless, the outcome I want is to have the method return "f8" as the outcome.

Comment: In `reVal` your `if` tests are using `=` instead of `==`: the latter is an equality test, the former is *assignment* and is surely not what you want.

Comment: @SteveFriedl alright, I fixed that, but I am still receiving the same error that I had previously with my return statement, res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `decToBase()` function, the issue it's warning about is the use of `char res[500];`, which is an array that's allocated on the stack as a local variable. These are all thrown away when the function returns, so if you return a pointer to (or: the address of) the `res` array, this pointer points to junk on the stack.

You have to find some other way to manage this allocation, and though some might suggest using `malloc()` to allocate memory from the system, this is probably a bad idea because it's asking for problems with memory leaks.

Better is to pass in the buffer you want it to fill, and use that. Then the *caller* does the allocation and you don't worry about memory leaks.

```
char *decToBase(int base, int dec, char *outbuf)
{
int index = 0; // Initialize index of result 
               // Convert input number is given base by repeatedly 
               // dividing it by base and taking remainder 
   while (dec > 0)
   {
      outbuf[index++] = reVal(dec % base);
      dec /= base;
   }

   outbuf[index] = '\0';
   // Reverse the result 
   strev(outbuf);
   return outbuf;
}
```

and then your `main` function would look like:

```
int main()
{
   char decbuf[500];

   decToBase(16, 248, decbuf);
   printf("Buffer is %s\n", decbuf);
}
```

This is still not super ideal, because your `decToBase()` function doesn't know how big `outbuf` is, and overflows are possible, so the experience and/or paranoid programmer will also pass in the size of outbuf so your function knows how much to use.

But that's a step you'll get to later.

Comment: can I call the char *outbuf out locally instead in the parameters? Will that work too?

Comment: I did it within the method. I called it out there. I now receive a warning with the malloc saying  warning: " incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ "

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you'd use it with `outbuf`; you really really should not use `malloc` because it's memory you have to keep track of, and it's far better to just pass the buffer as the updated code shows.

Comment: Alright, well it got rid of that warning. My only problem now is I receive a segmentation fault when I run the code. Also, in the main, you have it as a char but not a char *, even though the method has it like that. Is there an explanation with that? I struggle with Char pointers personally.

Comment: Oh I also declared it inside the method and not in the parameters. Is that fine?

Comment: If you're not using the code as shown, there's a fair chance you're going down the wrong road: declared *what* inside the method?

Pointers are always tricky and there's a certain learning curve for sure. When you pass the `decbuf` array to the function, it's not actually giving the whole array, but just a pointer to the start of that array - this is intentional.

Comment: I declared decbuf inside the function decToBase. Would that affect anything? It shouldn't though right?

Comment: Is there some reason you're not declaring it in main as has been offered?

Also: please look carefully at `strev()` and make sure it works correctly for strings of even length and of odd lengths, it doesn't look right.

Comment: I just want to see if I can try it without it being declared in the main. For a project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201574/discussion-between-steve-friedl-and-adan-vivero).

Comment: `decToBase(16, 0, decbuf);` --> `""` rather than `"0"`.

Comment: Well I was able to malloc it with the #include <stdlib.h> on the top.

Comment: Use of `malloc()` was a terrible idea in this case; I hope nobody consults this for an example

Comment: @SteveFriedl but it worked. What issues will it cause if I use it?

Comment: It "worked" but it leaked memory; it's just a bad practice, especially if you're learning. This is why I was trying to steer you down the other road with a caller-provided buffer.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Makes sense, but I was wondering if there were a way I could do it without having it in the parameter. Also, can't I free my memory?

Comment: This is a fair question, but in the end you have to take to heart the limitations of C: it's not a memory-managed language, and you have to *either* pass the output buffer as a parameter *or* deal with the consequences of memory management.

In my mind, this is a slam dunk: pass the output buffer to the function and tell it "put my stuff here".

This is how most of the C library is evolving, and it's just how it is. 

Is there a non-aesthetic reason you'd prefer not to do it this way?